# Perl Socket Connection Check

Tags: perl, socks

I've been trying to debug this perl issue for awhile but had made no head way. what I'm trying to do is determain if the connection is a socks4/5 connection.

```
# ./pctest.pl
Name "main::junk" used only once: possible typo at ./pctest.pl line 60.
Name "main::empty" used only once: possible typo at ./pctest.pl line 60.
IO::Socket::INET: Bad hostname 'C1(X'   ...propagated at ./pctest.pl line 52.
```

I've also had this error (before i added or die @$; at the end):

```
Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at ./pctest.pl line 56.
```

.

```
...
  $look = IO::Socket::INET->new( PeerAddr => $_, Proto => 'tcp', Timeout => 5 ) or die @$;

            $sock4 = pack( "CCS", 4, 1, 80 );

            print $look $sock4;

            read( $look, $recv, 10 );

            ( $empty, $granted, $junk ) = unpack( "C C C6", $recv );

            if( $granted == 0x5A )
            {
                    print " Yes\n";
            }
            else
            {
                    print " No\n";
            }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo. `@$` should really be `$@`.

To get rid of the "possible typo" messages and since `$empty` and `$junk` seem to be unused in your code, write:

```
my @result = unpack("C C C6", $recv);

if ($result[1] == 0x5A) {
# ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a side note : I think you are thinking of $@, instead of @$. You need to enclose the code in an

```
eval { ... };
```

construction. See:

```
my $look;
eval { $look = IO::Socket::INET->new( PeerAddr => $_, Proto => 'tcp', Timeout => 5 ) };

if ($@) {
   do_something_with($@);
}
```

Granted, that doesn't answer the original question :)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `eval` construct. I forgot that in my answer.

Comment: Oh and as an alternative to what goreSplatter said , you can also use ( undef, $granted ) = unpack( "C C C6", $recv );

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that your parameter value for `PeerAddr` in the `IO::Socket::INET->new` call is invalid.

The constructor expects the `PeerAddr` value to be a hostname or an IP address (nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn). Check the contents of `$_` and I bet you'll find something different.